# json sent to view but not able to take id from it jade template

Tags: json, node.js, pug

Please help me solve this. I'm new to `node` as well as `json`.
Something must have gone terribly wrong.

```
extends layout

block content
  h3 Trips selection #{trips}  //shows following json in the view
  form.form-horizontal(id="Findtrips", accept-charset="UTF-8", 
  action="#", method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data")
    each trip in trips
      p #{trip.tripId} //doesnt pusblish anything
```

`#{trips}` gives following:

```
{
  "onwardTrips": [{
    "tripId": "1285170",
    "fromCity": "Singapore",
    "toCity": "Malacca",
    "operatorCode": "SA",
    "operatorName": "Starmart Express",
    "departTime": "2014-01-20 20:00:00.0",
    "busType": "Executive",
    "pickupPointDetails": [{
      "pickupPointId": "78",
      "departureTime": "2014-01-20 20:00:00.0",
      "pickupPointName": "Golden Mile Tower, Beach Road"
    }],
    "dropoffPointDetails": [{
      "dropOffPointName": "Melaka Sentral",
      "dropOffPointId": "1285170"
    }],
    "fareDetails": {
      "adultFare": "65.0"
    }
  }, 
  {
    "tripId": "1285254",
    "fromCity": "Singapore",
    "toCity": "Malacca",
    "operatorCode": "SA",
    "operatorName": "Starmart Express",
    "departTime": "2014-01-20 23:00:00.0",
    "busType": "Executive",
    "pickupPointDetails": [{
      "pickupPointId": "78",
      "departureTime": "2014-01-20 23:00:00.0",
      "pickupPointName": "Golden Mile Tower, Beach Road"
    }],
    "dropoffPointDetails": [{
      "dropOffPointName": "Melaka Sentral",
      "dropOffPointId": "1285254"
    }],
    "fareDetails": {
      "adultFare": "65.0"
    }
  }],
  "errorCode": 0
}
```

server.js

```
getTrips: function getTrips(req, res, next){
     var url = 'CTB-WS/rest/trips?from='+ req.tripinfo.fromCityId + '&to=' + req.tripinfo.toCityId + '&depart-date=' + req.tripinfo.departDate+ '&pax=1';
     console.log(url);
     rest.get(url).on('complete', function(trips) {
      if (trips instanceof Error) {
        console.log('Error:', trips.message);
        } else {        
          console.log('trips'+ JSON.stringify(trips));  
          req.trips = JSON.stringify(trips);
          next();

        }
    });
  },

  sendTrips: function sendTrips(req, res, next){
    res.render('trips', {trips : req.trips});
  }
```

Comment: Please format your question properly. Jade is whitespace sensitive. If you can't figure out the markdown to format your question, maybe a whitespace-sensitive templating language is not the best choice for you.

Comment: sorry, yes i have formatted it.

Answer (score 0):

In your json(actually Javascript object), `trips` is not an array. Instead `trips.onwardTrips` is an array.
Please change `each` in jade like

```
if trips.onwardTrips
  each trip in trips.onwardTrips
    p #{trip.tripId}
```

Comment: I'm getting error.

TypeError: /home/jyoti/catchthatbus/views/trips.jade:6
    4|   h3 Trips selection <br>#{trips}
    5|     form.form-horizontal(id="Findtrips", accept-charset="UTF-8", action="#", method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data")
  > 6|       each trip in trips.onwardTrips
    7|         p #{trip.fromCity}
    8|     
    9|       

Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: Make sure `trips` have `onwardTrips` array. From the error, onwardTrips is undefined. I have updated answer to check whether `onwardTrips` exist in the object.

Answer (score 0):

solved it by following. I got trips.tripId now I want to get array inside trip i.e. dropoffPointDetails.

```
 getTrips: function getTrips(req, res, next){
     var url = 'CTB-WS/rest/trips?from='+ req.tripinfo.fromCityId + '&to=' + req.tripinfo.toCityId + '&depart-date=' + req.tripinfo.departDate+ '&pax=1';
     console.log(url);
     rest.get(url).on('complete', function(trips) {
      if (trips instanceof Error) {
        console.log('Error:', trips.message);
        } else {        
          console.log('trips'+ JSON.stringify(trips));  
          trips = trips || [];
          req.trips = trips['onwardTrips'];
          next();
        }
    });
  },

  sendTrips: function sendTrips(req, res, next){
    //res.render('trips', {trips : req.trips});
   res.render('trips', { trips: req.trips});

  }
```